# glTexSubImage2D not working

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm using android 4.1 and trying to use glTexSubImage2D on with NDK, without any success.
If I use glTexImage2D instead, it does work.

This works:

```
 // Creation: 
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tempTexture->mWidth, tempTexture->mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)tempTexture->mData);

 // Render loop:
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, info.width, info.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)pixels);
```

This doesn't work (I get nothing drawn):

```
 // Creation:
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tempTexture->mWidth, tempTexture->mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

 // Render loop:
 glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, info.width, info.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)pixels);
```

I made sure that the width and height are correct, but still it doesnt work - I get GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
yakobom

Comment: The man page lists the conditions under which glTexSubImage2D can emit GL_INVALID_ENUM, but the code you show certainly appears to be using valid values.  Are you sure the error is not coming from a previous call?  What device are you using?

Comment: Hi fadden, the error is not coming from a previous call, since when I use glTexImage2D only the texture is drawn and I get no error. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it. Apperantly, the width used in glTexSubImage2D was not always what it was supposed to be, it was sometimes a bit bigger...

Comment: do you use it for some video streaming? note that glTexImage can be quite slow (it recreates all the texture usually).

Comment: Something like that, it does require a few updates per secons for several seconds. But this is why I tried using glTexSubImage2D, it's supposed to be faster. Would you recommend something else?

Comment: subImage seems to be fine.. glTexImage is not recommended in such situation. in desktop opengl you can use Pixel buffer objects for instance.